# Authentication to SharePoint using secure authentication and CSOM in a .NET application

Tags: rest, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, authentication, .net

I'm using CSOM for making REST API calls to a SharePoint list from a C# application. This needs credentials *(of course)*, however I've found that it needs a username and a password in plain text. Something like code below:

```csharp
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com"))
{
    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication; 
    context.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("someone@domain.com", "P@ssw0rd");
    // Rest of the code
    context.ExecuteQuery(); // <-- error on this line
}
```

I've two issues with this code:

1. However I use the correct credentials, it's given me this error on the marked line:

   > The user's login name or password is not valid.
2. Security. It's not secure to add the credentials in plain text in the code.

I've also tried code below, but I get a 403 response *(also with the correct credentials)* and it's not secure too.

```csharp
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com"))
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someone@domain.com", "P@ssw0rd");
    // Rest of the code
    context.ExecuteQuery(); // <-- error on this line
}
```

In the header stand this:

> Access denied. Before opening files in this location: you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.

How can I solve this, especially the second issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint Online requires SecureString object as password. You can do something like this:

```
 SecureString se = new SecureString();
 foreach (var cc in password)
 {
     se.AppendChar(cc);
 }
 var cre = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("someone@domain.com", se);
 using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://site.sharepoint.com"))
 {
     context.Credentials = cre;
     // Rest of the code
     context.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```

To solve the plain text password problem, you can store it in the Windows Credential Manager then retrieve it using this Library
[CredentialManager](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Utilities/CredentialManager.cs)

Comment: Yes you can do that but `SecureString` requires a plain text password too.

Comment: That's why I recommend CredentialManager class which returns SharePointOnlineCredential object `var credential = CredentialManager.GetSharePointOnlineCredential(name);`